# Managed bean property not being set on commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:dialog` containing a `p:dataTable`; when a row gets selected I want to enable a `p:commandButton` and when clicked a textarea should be updated - but the textarea component appears af it was validated (red outlining) and the value is always null.

The textarea:

```
<c:set property="resolution" value="#{cc.attrs.resolution}" target="#{cc.attrs.bean}" />
...
<h:outputLabel for="resolution" value="#{text['task.action.resolution']}" />
<p:inputTextarea id="resolution" 
             rows="10"
             value="#{cc.attrs.bean.resolution}"                
             required="true" requiredMessage="#{text['task.action.required.resolution']}"
             />
```

The dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="userNotesDialog"
          widgetVar="userNotesDialogVar" 
          header="#{text['task.action.user_notes']}"                      
          ... >
    <p:dataTable id="userNotesTable"
                value="#{cc.attrs.bean.userNotesOptions}"
                rendered="#{!cc.attrs.bean.userNotesOptions.isEmpty()}"
                var="userNote"
                selection="#{cc.attrs.bean.selectedUserNote}"                             
                selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{userNote.id}">            
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  
                listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.onUserNoteSelect}"
                update=":#{cc.clientId}:actionForm:chooseUserNote"
    />                                            
        <p:column>
        Some content here
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>    
    <p:commandButton id="chooseUserNote"
        disabled="#{cc.attrs.bean.selectedUserNote == null}"
        value="#{text['task.action.user_notes.select']}"                                              
        action="#{cc.attrs.bean.setResolutionWithUserNote}"
        oncomplete="PF('userNotesDialogVar').hide()"      
        update=":#{cc.clientId}:actionForm:parentPanel :#{cc.clientId}:actionForm:resolution">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{cc.attrs.bean.resolution}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.selectedUserNote.noteText}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
```

Note: the whole code is enclosed by a form (`actionForm`).

When the dialog is closed, the `resolution` component is supposed to filled with the selected value, but it appears to be null - am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a forgotten `c:set` that was reposting the initial value to the `textarea` component. The problem was solved when `c:set` was removed.

Comment: As an aside, for properly troubleshooting the problem, it would have been necessary to add the relevant parts of the backing bean to the question.

Comment: Yes, I should've posted a bit more of code. My use case is somewhat complex, and I tried to simplify it in order to make the question easier to understand - or maybe I should've posted at least the `c:set` calls, but then again, if I'd have posted that, I probably would have been able to identify the issue.

Comment: I edited the question with the `c:set` code since it can refer to a problem that other users may have (`c:set` reposts the value into the variable on updates) - so I don't think this should be closed